# Assign label to categorical data in a table in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I want to assign the label to the categorical numbers in a dataframe below using pyspark sql.

In the MARRIAGE column 1=Married and 2=Unmarried. In the EDUCATION Column 1=Grad and 2=Undergrad

```
Current Dataframe:
+--------+---------+-----+
|MARRIAGE|EDUCATION|Total|
+--------+---------+-----+
|       1|        2|   87|
|       1|        1|  123|
|       2|        2|    3|
|       2|        1|    8|
+--------+---------+-----+
```

```
Resulting Dataframe:
+---------+---------+-----+
|MARRIAGE |EDUCATION|Total|
+---------+---------+-----+
|Married  |Grad     |   87|
|Married  |UnderGrad|  123|
|UnMarried|Grad     |    3|
|UnMarried|UnderGrad|    8|
+---------+---------+-----+
```

Is it possible to assign the labels using a single udf and the withColumn()? Is there any way to assign in the single UDF by passing the whole dataframe and keep the column names as it is?

I can think of a solution to do the operation on each column by using separate udfs as below. But can't figure out if there's a way to do together.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def assign_marital_names(record):
    if record == 1:
        return "Married"
    elif record == 2:
        return "UnMarried"


def assign_edu_names(record):
    if record == 1:
        return "Grad"
    elif record == 2:
        return "UnderGrad"

assign_marital_udf = F.udf(assign_marital_names)
assign_edu_udf = F.udf(assign_edu_names)
df.withColumn("MARRIAGE", assign_marital_udf("MARRIAGE")).\
withColumn("EDUCATION", assign_edu_udf("EDUCATION")).show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One UDF can result in only one column. But this can be structured column and UDF can apply labels on both marriage and education. See code below:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row

udf_result = StructType([StructField('MARRIAGE', StringType()), StructField('EDUCATION', StringType())]) 

marriage_dict = {1: 'Married', 2: 'UnMarried'}
education_dict = {1: 'Grad', 2: 'UnderGrad'}
def assign_labels(marriage, education):
    return Row(marriage_dict[marriage], education_dict[education])

assign_labels_udf = F.udf(assign_labels, udf_result)
df.withColumn('labels', assign_labels_udf('MARRIAGE', 'EDUCATION')).printSchema()
root
 |-- MARRIAGE: long (nullable = true)
 |-- EDUCATION: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Total: long (nullable = true)
 |-- labels: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- MARRIAGE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- EDUCATION: string (nullable = true)
```

But as you see, it's not replacing the original columns, it's just adding a new one. To replace them you will need to use `withColumn` twice and then drop `labels`.